# Do changes made inside a hook persist after the hook has finished evaluation?

Tags: hooks

Let's say I am setting a variable to a value inside a hook. I'm hooking the hook to the `minibuffer-setup-hook` so that it runs whenever the minibuffer opens. Will the changes made by the hook persist after I close the minibuffer? Or will they revert back to their original state?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what kind of changes you make. There's nothing special about code invoked from a hook.

If you set a global variable it remains set until something sets it differently or `makunbound`s it.

Your question is general, so the answer is general. If you pose a specific question, e.g. with some code, specific answers can likely be given.